# PriorityQueue.poll();

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, queue, priority-queue

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the best way to modify an object's compareTo function so that when the parent priority queue's "poll()" function is called the lowest non-negative value is returned, as opposed to the lowest value in general?

Say, we have a Number class that stores any number, negative or non-negative, but I don't want the data from an object of that class returned if it's negative.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your Queue inside a wrapper object, and never add negative values. Then you can use your queue as normal, knowing the lowest value will be non-negative.

<del>Here's a rough draft. I didn't compile it or anything,  but it's an idea.</del> Here's an example of that.

```
import java.util.*;
class PositiveQueue<E extends Number> extends PriorityQueue<Number> {

    public boolean offer(E e) {
        if(isNegative(e)) return false;
        return super.offer(e);
    }

    private static boolean isNegative(Number n) {
        // add logic here
        return n.intValue() < 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PositiveQueue<Short> q = new PositiveQueue<Short>();
        q.offer((short)4);
        q.offer((short)7);
        q.offer((short)2);
        q.offer((short)-5);
        q.offer((short)5);

        while(q.peek() != null) System.out.println(q.poll());
    }

}

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac PositiveQueue.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java PositiveQueue
2
4
5
7
```

Comment: Is there no way to simply modify the compareTo of the Number class to ensure that negative values aren't returned? I do want the queue to store negative values; I just don't want it to return negative values when looking for the lowest number.

Comment: No. And why would you want to modify the compareTo of number? You don't want to change how they're compared system wide, just inside your class. What do you plan to do with negative numbers while you store them?

Comment: So how do you want the negative values in the queue to be treated?

Comment: Oh, I think there's a bit of misunderstanding here. I wasn't talking about Java's Number class; I just came up with a name for some class as an example (I'm trying to modify a class I've written myself, which of course has a different name).

Comment: @HannoBinder 

I want them to be ignored when the .poll() function is called. If the queue contains -5, 2, and 7, it would return 2, not -5.

Comment: @Edward the problem is still the same. How do you want to handle negative numbers? If the Queue has ONLY negative numbers, should one be returned then? Or should null? How should negative number numbers ever be accessed from outside the Queue? Should they be included in the size of the Queue? You see, there are big problems to solve here if we let them exist in the queue when we don't want them to show up!

Comment: @Edward to rephrase that... if you want them ignored when you `poll()`, when do you NOT want them ignored?

Comment: I want them not ignored everywhere else; it's just in the poll() function where I want them ignored.

To put things into perspective, I'm trying to implement this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) algorithm, where -1 is being used as a marker to represent infinity.

Comment: @Edward Then you're better off not using -1 for that. Instead, use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or some other very very large number.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's sort things out a little:

1. You *want* to put negative numbers into your queue?
2. You *do not* want those numbers to be returned *at all* when de-queueing elements?
3. What else do you want to do with those numbers which *are* in the queue but will never *leave* the queue again?

A queue in Java can only hold objects, by the way, so you can use `null` instead of some other magic value.

I assume you need to allow duplicate values in your implementation. If not, though, have a look at implementations of [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).